# 'Finish in first place' v. 'finish in THE first place'

Tags: grammar, articles

Why is there no 'the' before the numbers in expressions like 'finish in first place'? Even Grammarly underlines it. What is the grammatical explanation?

Comment: In BE, at least, if you add "the",  the phrase takes on a new meaning:** In the first place** = **(i)** before you do anything else: "In the first place, you will need a hammer, otherwise there will be nothing to drive in the nails." **(ii)** before you are able to do anything else; "You will need a lot of money in the first place of you want to live on your investments." **(iii)** Introducing the primary reason "You said that, at the hotel, I stole your watch: in the first place, I was not in the hotel, ..." (This would continue: "and in the second place, I see that you are wearing a watch.")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In first place", is a fixed phrase, meaning before all other finishers in a contest. The word "first" acts as a determiner, uniquely identifying the particular "place" involved. It may be contrasted with "second place" and "third place", also usually without an additional determiner.
In some cases, when "first-place" is used as an adjective, it may be preceded by "the", for example, "the first-place finisher", but then the word "the" belongs to the noun "finisher".

"In the first place..." has a different meaning, and is defined in dictionaries, for example,
[Merriam-Webster "in the first place"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20the%20first%20place)

> 1 —used at the end of a sentence to indicate what was true or what should have been done at the beginning of a situation
> *We should never have gone there in the first place.I didn't care much for the job in the first place.*
> 2 —used when listing the most important parts of something or the most important reasons for something
> *I'm not going to tell you because, in the first place, it's none of your business, and in the second place, you would tell everyone else.*

In that sense, "the first place" may be contrasted with "the second place" or "secondly".